# Append new category to existing category list via Magento Dataprofile Import

Tags: magento-1.8, category

I have a situation where i need to create a new Category ( say Promotional ) and add around 1000+ product to it.

I tried it by creating a csv file as below format.

```
"sku","category_ids"
"C028367835486","3513"
```

But instead of appending new category, it has replaced existing category.

Is their a way were i can append category to existing category list?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You need to put all category_ids to associate the product with in this column. Instead of just putting the new category here, put both the old and new category_ids seperated by comma.

Keep in mind the category would need to already exist to do it this way.

Another option is using Magmi, a robust import platform made for Magento. It has a category creater/importer plugin that works wonders for things like this. More info can be found at http://wiki.magmi.org